# Why do i get null in request parameter in servlet?

Tags: java, jsp

Well from my form i have gotten a specific database column into a input box in jsp form , it is sucessful however the issue is i also want to get it into backend using request paramater but i get null as a result .

The jsp form code:

```
<form style="height: 100% ; width: 100% ; margin-top: 5% ; margin-right: 0%" method="GET">
                    
                            <table class="styled-table" style="margin-bottom: 15px; margin-top:0%; height: 80%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Doctor Name</th>  
                                        <th>Speciality</th>  
                                        <th>Channel</th>  
                                        
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                <%
                                    String input = request.getParameter("input");

                                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hms", "root", "");
                                    Statement st = con.createStatement();
                                    ResultSet rs = null;
                                    String strQuery;
                                    if (input != null) {
                                        strQuery = " SELECT * FROM staff WHERE Staff_Name like '%" + input + "%' or Staff_speciality like '%" + input + "%' AND Position= 'Doctor'  ";
                                    } else {
                                        strQuery = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE Position= 'Doctor' ";
                                    }
                                    rs = st.executeQuery(strQuery);
                                    if (rs != null) {
                                        while (rs.next()) {
                                %>
                                <tr class="row">
                                    <td><%=rs.getString("Staff_Name")%><input name="docname" type="text"  value="<%=rs.getString("Staff_Name")%>"></td>
                                    <td><%=rs.getString("Staff_speciality")%></td>
                                    
                                   
                                    <td><a title="Channel Now " style=" display: flex; justify-content:center; align-items: center; color:#39447a;" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ChannelDoc/channel"><i style="margin-left: 4%;" class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i></a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <% }
                                    }
                                %>
                            </tbody> 
                               
                            </table >
                        </form>
```

The code used to send to servlet:

```
<a title="Channel Now " style=" display: flex; justify-content:center; align-items: center; color:#39447a;" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ChannelDoc/channel">
```

The servlet code :

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getServletPath().contains("/channel")) {
            
           String name=request.getParameter("docname");
           System.out.print(name);
}
```

The servlet provides me null as a result I cant proceed to continue with other backend work , any help would be really appreciated to get the docname value in servlet.

Thank you for all in advance.

Comment: How is that `input` sent to the servlet?

Comment: The code to send to servlet is:  <a title="Channel Now " style=" display: flex; justify-content:center; align-items: center; color:#39447a;" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ChannelDoc/channel">

Comment: Please don't use comments for that. Please [edit] your question instead.

Comment: And in general please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Anyway, how does an `a` submit a form? Your servlet is expecting a GET parameter you're not sending. You should either include that field inside a `form` and submit the form, or that `a` should trigger some piece of JavaScript that opens the link appending `?docname=XXXX` (where XXXX is the content of the field) to it

Comment: its inside an form and a td tag didn't want to show all code wanted to make it easy to read through

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232176/discussion-between-ryan-anjelo-and-federico-klez-culloca).

Comment: Parameters need to be sent. If you're sending a request via a link the parameter needs to be in the URL (e.g., a typical GET parameter like you'd expect). Unrelated: You've basically enabled complete DB access in your JSP. Please reconsider (a) where your DB access occurs, and (b) not building query strings with raw concatenation.

Comment: You may want to consider taking a step back for a moment: ignoring the scriptlet in JSP (this is almost always a bad idea), how to get a parameter from a JSP to the back end is pretty basic functionality. A quick tutorial might be a good idea. Generally a form would be used; not that a link *can't* be used, but it may not be the best approach.

Comment: thanks i will note that